# Struggling to map an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fetching data from backend, and I want to map everything. However I am struggling to render an array of objects . `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cargoType')`

Anyways, here's my code.. I tried to map it in a few different ways such as

```
  const displayDashboard = bookings?.map((booking: BookingInterface, index) => (
    <Text key={index}>{Object.values(booking?.pallets[index].cargoType)}</Text>
));
```

`<Text key={index}>{booking.pallets.cargoType}</Text>` (seems to return nothing) and a few other ideas that came to my mind like: `booking.pallets[index].cargoType` returns 'cannot read properties of undefined'. HOWEVER, I am unable to get any data, except if I do
`Object.values(booking?.pallets[index]` I receive an array of indexes like so: `01234`

Here's how the data looks like (took out a few other entries besides 'pallets' to make it look cleaner):

```
0:
pallets: Array(5)
0: {cargoType: 'Engines & spare parts', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6092', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
1: {cargoType: 'Furniture and accessories/Ceramics', stackable: false, cargoValue: '16485', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
2: {cargoType: 'Engines & spare parts', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6879', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
3: {cargoType: 'New Vehicles', stackable: false, cargoValue: '19980', count: '4', dangerous: false, …}
4: {cargoType: 'Industrial products', stackable: false, cargoValue: '9516', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

1:
pallets: Array(4)
0: {cargoType: 'Chemicals & healthcare', stackable: false, cargoValue: '5741', count: '3', dangerous: false, …}
1: {cargoType: 'Old Vehicles', stackable: false, cargoValue: '18877', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
2: {cargoType: 'Paperboard & prints', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6841', count: '1', dangerous: false, …}
3: {cargoType: 'Chemicals & healthcare', stackable: false, cargoValue: '7558', count: '1', dangerous: false, …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Not really sure why isn't it rendering any data back. I was hoping to get it going with a simple `booking.pallets.cargoType`, but no - everything renders except this line. I believe that I am targeting the data improperly, but I ran out of ideas on how to get it to show up.

Comment: You're using the current index of `bookings` to reference `booking.pallets`.  What guarantee do you have that `pallets` will always have at least as many elements as that `booking`'s index?  For example, if the `booking` at index 4 has a `pallets` array with 3 elements, then clearly `pallets[4]` will fail.  It's not really clear to me what you're expecting to output here.

Comment: well, I want to output the value from 'cargoType' - regardless of how many entries there are.. i want all of them

Comment: my guess is that I should map ``` booking.pallets.map(x => ( x.cargoType ) ``` - what do you think about this solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects.  Each object has multiple properties.  One of those properties is an array.  That is **not the same array**.

Basically, you need a loop (or `.map()`) for the array of `bookings`, and **for each booking** you need a loop (or a `.map()`) for the array of `pallets`.  The structure is the same, one is just inside the other.

For example:

```
const displayDashboard = bookings?.map((booking, bi) => (
  <React.Fragment key={bi}>
    {booking?.pallets?.map((pallet, pi) => (
      <Text key={pi}>{pallet?.cargoType)}</Text>
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
));
```

(Wrapped in a `Fragment` so we can apply a `key` without changing the markup.  If you want to group the values in the markup, a `<div>` or any other such element would work just as well.)

Comment: I was just thinking that when you answered initially. Thank you! Appreciate you taking the time to understand and help me out. Wish you all the best!